# How can I make apigateway forward root path to integrated http endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I created a REST api gateway in AWS and configure it to pass through all requests to a http endpoint. The configuration I have is

[image]

After deploy to a stage (dev) it gives me an invoke URL, like `https://xxxx.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/dev`,

it works fine if I invoke the url by appending a sub path like: [https://xxxx.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/dev/xxxxx`](https://xxxx.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/dev/xxxxx%60), I can see it forward the request to downstream http endpoint. However it doesn't forward any request if I invoke the base url:  `https://xxxx.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/dev`. How can I make it work with the base invoke url without any subpath?

I tired to add an additional `/` path resource in API gateway but it doesn't allow me to add it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application must be able to receive requests at any path, including the root path: /. An API Gateway resource with a path of /{proxy+} captures every path except the root path. Making a request for the root path results in a 403 response from API Gateway with the message Missing Authentication Token.

To fix this omission, add an additional resource to the API with the path set to / and link that new resource to the same http endpoint as used in the existing /{proxy+} resource.

The updated OpenAPI document now looks like the following code example:

```
{
    "openapi": "3.0",
    "info": {
        "title": "All-capturing example",
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    "paths": {
        "/": {
            "x-amazon-apigateway-any-method": {
                "responses": {},
                "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
                    "httpMethod": "POST",
                    "type": "aws_proxy",
                    "uri": ""
                }
            }
        },
        "/{proxy+}": {
            "x-amazon-apigateway-any-method": {
                "responses": {},
                "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
                    "httpMethod": "POST",
                    "type": "aws_proxy",
                    "uri": ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How to add a resource `/` in API gateway? I got this error ` Resource's path part only allow a-zA-Z0-9._- or a valid greedy path variable and curly braces at the beginning and the end.
`.

Comment: I have updated the answer, I hope this can help

Comment: I wonder how you can do that in API gateway. I have updated my qusetion and leave a screenshot. It doesn't allow me to create a resource with path `/`.

Comment: You do not need to create another child resource, just go to / resource and create another  ANY method